Difference between node (or ECU) id and frame id for can bus
I'm diving into the intricacies of CAN bus communication and came across the terms "Node ID" and "Frame ID." While both seem to play crucial roles, I'm a bit confused about their differences. Could someone shed some light on this? And can I change the "Node (or ECU) ID"?

When speaking of any form of data communication, it is important to be aware of the OSI model. Normally in embedded systems, it can be simplified to 3 layers: physical, data link and application.
CAN (aka "high speed CAN" aka ISO 11898-2) only specifies the physical and data link layers. It does not specify the application tier.
Node id is an application tier concept, specified by some application tier standards like for example CANopen. If the application tier specifies no such term, then "node id" doesn't make sense in CAN. And so speaking of node id without specifying the application tier is nonsense. Just as it is nonsense to take any random CAN bus and attempting to decode the contents without knowing which application tier it uses.
Frame id on the other hand, is just an alias for message id or CAN identifier, which is a data link layer concept specified by CAN. Every CAN frame/message has an identifier and knowing how this works is the most fundamental part of the CAN bus. CAN - the data link layer - does not specify node addresses, masters or slaves etc. It is a message-oriented bus where every node on the bus listens to every other node. By looking at the identifier, a node decides if it is interested in the contents or if it should just ignore them. The identifier also plays a fundamental part in bus arbitration and message priorities. Again, this is the most fundamental thing of all in CAN communication, so any introductory training material will explain it very early on.

When using SocketCAN on a Raspberry Pi:
Node ID: SocketCAN does not directly use Node IDs as CAN does not have device-specific addressing. You can manage device identification at the application layer or by conventionally using parts of the Frame ID.
Frame ID: Set the Frame ID for message priority directly in your code using the can_id field of the can_frame structure. This ID determines message priority, with lower numbers having higher priority.
for example
struct can_frame frame;
frame.can_id = 0x123;  // Frame ID for priority
frame.can_dlc = 8;     // Data length code

specify the Frame ID when constructing CAN frames, adjusting frame.can_id for each message based on its priority and intended device function if using ID conventions for Node ID.

Thanks for the detailed explanation! While I grasp the general concepts of Node ID and Frame ID, I'm specifically interested in how they come into play when using SocketCAN on a Raspberry Pi to communicate with devices.
For instance, if I'm interfacing with devices over CAN using SocketCAN on a Raspberry Pi, how do I specify the device ID (Node ID) and the message priority (Frame ID) in my code? Are there specific functions or configurations within SocketCAN that facilitate this?
